# Symfony2 Form Rest Api only add to Relation

Tags: rest, symfony, symfony-forms

I am using Symfony2 as Rest Api for a JS Frontend App. I came across a scenario where I want users to "invite" (=add) Users to a Group. But I want to only allow them to add Users to the existing Relation and not "overwrite" the whole relation, which is the standard behaviour in combination with a regular Symfony2 Form.

What would be the best practice to achieve this behaviour?

Additional Comment:

I am using Ember-Data in the frontend and my frontend would probably send a put request with the whole Group including additional users (but not all).

My JSON Payload would look something like this:

```
{
    "usergroup": {
        "name":"yxcv2",
        "stake":"sdfghj",
        "imageName":null,
        "userCount":5,
        "users":[
            5,
            6,
            7
            ],
        "gameGroup":"13",
    }
}
```

In this scenario User 1,2,3 and 4 are already members of the group. And instead of replacing 1,2,3,4 with 5,6,7, I want to ADD 5,6,7 to the already existing members.

Comment: can you explain "send a put request with the whole Group including additional users (**but not all**)", please ?

Answer (score 0):

A **[`LINK`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/Methods/Link.html)** request should be used to add an item to an existing collection instead of overwriting it with a `POST` request.

Using a symfony form you'd post the `User` (id) plus a hidden field `_method` with value `LINK` to something like `/groups/{id}`.

routing would be something like this:

```
group_invite:
    path:     /groups/{id}
    defaults: { _controller: YourBundle:Group:inviteUser }
    methods:   [LINK]
```

You could use FOSRestBundle's **[implicit resource name definition](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/5-automatic-route-generation_single-restful-controller.md#implicit-resource-name-definition)**, too.

For the method override to work the config setting `framework.http_method_override` needs to be set to `true` ( = default value - available since symfony version 2.3).

More information can be found in the documentation chapter:

**[How to use HTTP Methods beyond GET and POST in Routes](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/method_parameters.html)**

Comment: This would make sense from a plain "REST" perspective, I am using Ember-Data in the frontend and it would probably make a "PUT" request for "updates" on existing entities.